# How do you create a database from an EDM?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ado.net

How do you create a database from an Entity Data Model.

So I created a database using the EDM Designer in VisualStudio 2008, and now I want to generate the SQL Server Schema to create storage in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are not just supposed to use EDM as a "pretty" database designer, in fact EDM does not depend on a specific storage layer. It tries to abstract that part for the developer. There are design schemas (CSDL) and storage schemas (SSDL). Anyway, don't mean to lecture you. ;)

There is [EDM Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx), which you use to create models and class, etc.. For a DDL kind of export, I've never done that but what I did was map my EDM to an existing database, which was easier for me to get started.

There is a great tutorial on MSDN, which details step by step instructions on how to go about using an existing database, but also touches the how to start from scratch approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163286.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The Feature "Generate Database Schema from Model" is scheduled for a future release of Entity Framework. V1 does'nt support schema generatiorn based on EF models.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other answers implied this, but just to be explicit - use SSMS (or whatever equivlent if you're a brave sole and not using SQL Server provider) to design the DB layout and then suck that into EDM - and then apply application changes as necessary to the model.

I spent about an hour trying to do it your way first (leftover habit from some other Java ORM tools) - I eventually gave up and now do it the 'Right Way' (tm)

Eventually it would be nice (as JRoppert indicated) to have the generate databse schema from model feature - then you could get your DDLs for various DB flavours automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Generating databases from model is a feature planned for vNext of Entity Framework. 
Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/09/10/model-first.aspx) of [Entity Framework Design](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/default.aspx) explaining the planned features for database generation from a model.

What you must do right now is either 1) generate the database by hand, or 2) parse the CSDL file and write your own generator. I think option 1) is probably a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Avilable in EF 4:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/09/10/model-first.aspx